# Export Macro Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a macro setup where on the click of a button it exports the data to an excel file, it runs smoothly it seems until the end where I get the error RUN TIME ERROR 3434 CANNOT EXPAND NAMED RANGE

The code is:

```
Public Sub ExportTblToExcel()
Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\"
Dim FULLPath As String
strFullPath = FILE_PATH
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel7, "tblExport", strFullPath & "CD_Data.xlsx", False
MsgBox ("Export Complete. Check the C:\ Drive for the Document CD_Data")
End Sub
```

The portion that is highlighted on the error is:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel7, "tblExport", strFullPath & "CD_Data.xlsx", False
```

I cannot figure out what the error is, it has worked in the past up until now.

Comment: Tried that, I got the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acSpreadsheetTypeExcel7` is for Excel 95 format, but you want to create an .xlsx file. So I think you should specify a different spreadsheet type. Try `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`.

Also create your workbook file somewhere other than C:\.  Pick a folder where the user has file create privilege.  C:\Temp\ should work.

Comment: Tried both your suggestions and got the same error each time.

Comment: Does it matter that I have office 2013?

Comment: The next thing I would suggest is to try creating the file somewhere other than `C:\.`  Does your code work with this change? `Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\"`

Comment: Follow Up: Is there DoCmd or another way to have the excel file auto open when the export is complete?

Comment: `Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\share\Access\temp.xls"` <== adjust path to taste.

Comment: OK I will try that, for some reason I am getting the same error as before now. (Not talking about the Application.FollowHyperLink) but when I click the button to run the query I am getting the same cannot expand named range error, it worked a second ago but now it is not.

Answer (score 0):

To use automation to open the excel file use something like ... bottom part of routine

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myDate As String
    Dim xlApp As Object

    myDate = Day(txtEnd) & "-" & Month(txtEnd) & "-" & Year(txtEnd)
    myFile = WorkingDbFolder & "DKRForAccounts_" & myDate & ".xls"

    'create temp table with combined data
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryrptAccounts_XXX"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryrptAccounts_XXXDepRuns"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    MsgBox "Excel about to open ... This only summaries Customers with an Email Address"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblTEMP_XXXaccounts", myFile, True

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlApp.Workbooks.Open myFile, True, False

    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```